Pixel 4 stops charging or discharging on rooted LineageOS
I got a Pixel 4 a couple of months ago (it had been stored for years but barely used). I then installed rooted LineageOS and Kali NetHunter apps with chroot (this didn't cause the issue I think). Just yesterday, it was working fine when I started messing around with the WiFi card firmware in nexmon. I am not sure if the issue was caused by that because I don't see how the WiFi chip would affect the battery. Today, the battery indicator won't go down when not charging or up when charging. Also, the issue isn't LineageOS because I shut it down and it still has the issue on the charging but not on screen.
